# Acumatica Gets Data from Another Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, acumatica

How to get all record data from master data to another grid without change anything from master data and save it into new grid like this picture

[image]

into this grid

[image]

In the header, I have routingID and I want to get my operationMaster into my new grid in picture 2, any suggestion... I try with PXSelectJoin but it just gets data in master routing, and if I delete the line in picture 2 in my master will be deleted too. i want to get data just in screen to save it in into picture 2

Any Suggestion...

Answer (score 0):

create a db table that will contain data from grid2, corrsponding DAC (dac2) and graph (graph2).
Then you can use an graph2 action to import data from grid1 to grid2. In the action you read data from grid1 using PXSelect ..., and insert it into corresponfing data view of graph2 which contains DAC2 records.

Comment: how  to get import data from grid1? with foreach from my PXSelect or ? can you give me some example.

Comment: right, with foreach from your data view bound to grid1.

Comment: i still cant understand with that, i try it but still failed